# charged with assault, charter right sec 10(b) violated

Tags: canada, ontario, assault, charge-dismissed

This is in Canada.

Police laid an assault charge against me after my wife called 911 during our quarrel, she was in baby blue.

While in the police station, the officer prepare some paperwork for me to sign, and told me i can speak to a duty consel over the phone, he also asked me if i need other language service as English is not my first language. Then i said yes, i wanted to talk to someone that speaks my mother language. I also explained the reason as because there might be alot of terminologies which i could not understand. There were 2 officers, and both officers agreed.

Then i was returned to the room, and few minutes later, the officer opened the door and told me the duty consel was on the phone now, but he speaks English. It seemed i had no other choice even though i requested a mother language cousel service. Then i talked with the gentleman( he told me once his name over the phone, but i did hear clearly and did not remember)over the phone, as i worried, a big amount of the conversation i did not understand, like the gentleman said i must sign some forms, i repeated this several times trying to understand what are them, such as the name of the forms, the purpose of the forms, and so forth, because i was nervous about signing anything.

I clearly requested a specific language for the right to consel service, but was provided with an English service, does this mean my Charter right has been violated. On top of this, the whole process (from the begining when the police arrived my home) was questionable as what we said were ignored, they were just writing or taking things according to their own available resources, traditions, procedures, experiences, and many other irrelevant stuffs.

I did a lot of research on the web, but can anyone let me know was my charter right being violated? how to reach and request the Crown dismiss/drop the case?

I do not have a lawyer (can not afford), then where to reach out.

what I am thinking about are:
1, to mentioned that during the court, such as to the duty consel at the court；
2, to drop a letter about this to the Crown office;
3, to contact the Ministry of the Attornet General by email

Comment: If you can't afford a lawyer, you definitely can't afford not to have one. Legal support or aid services are generally available, as you have experienced, and they are your best first avenue.

Comment: *"she was in baby blue."* What does that mean? She was/is pregnant?

Comment: @RonBeyer I think it's referring to Post-Partum Depression, sometimes called "the baby blues"